# Cant find folder and variable under res folder

Tags: java, android, video, resources

I am new with android development and I created a new folder under **res** folder named **videos** and then I put a video file in it to use in the app. following is my code in attempt to use the video file.

```
package com.example.touseef.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView MyVideoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MyVideoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.videos.bang);
    MyVideoView.start();
}
}
```

**ERROR** : It was giving error **cannot find variable R.videos** before, but then I tried to clean and rebuilt project after starting android studio, and it asked me for somelinking with bang.mp4 file as text document and I said ok.

Now when I try to build it, the bang.mp4 file opens in a text form within android studio and I receive following error.

**Content is not allowed in prolog**

**Note:** I cant see the folder **videos** under **res** folder within **android view** in android studio but folder does exist as I can see it in **FileEx plorer** in my pc and it also has that video file in it. Also note that when I restart my project, I can see the folder, but it again disappears after android studio completes loading with indexing of my project.

Answer (score 4):

`res/videos` is not a valid resource folder. You'll need to put your video into `res/raw` and refer to it from `R.raw`. Have a look at the [Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) section of the Android documentation. One important gotcha to keep in mind though:

> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the `assets/` directory (instead of `res/raw/`). Files in `assets/` are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using `AssetManager`.

Answer (score 3):

Create raw folder inside res folder and put your videos in that folder

```
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
    Uri video = Uri.parse(uri);
    VideoView videoView=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            videoView.start();
        }
    });
```